# how to read resources from app.xml

Tags: windows-phone-7

I defined some resources in app.xml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <maps:MapGlobalSettings x:Key="MapGlobalSettings" ApiKey="1234567890" />
</Application.Resources>
```

How can I read it from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read global resources like

```
App.Current.Resources["MapGlobalSettings"]
```

It returns object, so you have to cast it to the original type